# I would like to style the color of a button to primary if the selected button value equals to any of the `key` of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to style the color of a button to primary, if the `patient.locationInfo` equals to any of the `key` of `longName2ShortName` object.

```
const longName2ShortName = {
        'Fishing': 'F',
        'Garden': 'G',
        'Running': 'R',
        'Shower': 'S',
        'Exercise': 'E',
        'Toilet': 'T',
    };
```

I've tried

```
    <div> 
        {patientInfo.map((patient, index) => {

    <Button bsStyle={Object.keys(longName2ShortName).map(key => key === patient.locationInfo? 'primary' : 'default')}> </Button> 

     )}
    </div>
```

error i'm getting with my code

`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop bsStyle of value default,default,primary,default,default,default,default,default,default supplied to Button, expected one of ["success","warning","danger","info","default","primary","link"].`

Comment: So... ```className={ longName2ShortName[patient.locationInfo] ? `primary` : `somethingelse` }```? (or bStyle, but we have no idea what your `<Button>` class does, so whatever attribute works).

Comment: Do you mean to `find` instead of `map`? It's not clear why you're using the object as an iterable--typically, you'd want to look up using the key to get the value rather than linear search the values. Your code produces something like `<Button bsStyle={['primary', 'default', 'default', 'primary'....]}> </Button> ` hence the error. Can you provide a [mcve] so the problem can be properly diagnosed? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you for your answer. My approach with map was wrong, what I should of done is on Mike's answer above. I'll keep the mininal repoducible example in my mind. And thanks for leading me on the right direction to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reread your description: you want to set a value to `primary` if [some value] equals to any of the keys that exist on object `longName2ShortName`.

So combine those. You could check whether an object has a specific key by using `Object.keys()` but this is really silly if you also know that all your keys correspond to real values. We can just reference the object and see if we get a value back or not:

```
longName2ShortName[patient.locationInfo] // either some value, or `undefined`
```

So, since this will either be a value if `patient.locationInfo` matches one of the keys, or `undefined` if it doesn't, we can use that in a ternary and we're immediately done:

```
<Button
  bsStyle={ longName2ShortName[patient.locationInfo] ? `primary` : `default` }
  key={ patient.name }
/>
```

And remember to [add that `key` attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component). It's the one crucial requirement when mapping state to React components. React *needs to know* which component maps to which object, so it can correctly apply diffs, which it uses `key` for.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you very much for your answer. My understanding of working with JS objects isn't the best. Your answers helped be better understand and worked in my app too. My approach with my code was wrong and unnecessary. I'll look into accessing JS Objects & when to correctly use Object.keys.